# Check processor status- check processor/cpu status and failed/off status

Tags: solaris, unix-shell

I want to Check processor status- check processor/cpu status and failed/off status so for that I used command prtdiag and want to fetch the cpu status only from that. how can i do that?

Comment: What is prtdiag part of?  A virtual hosting platform?  It doesn't seem to be a standard Unix utility.

Comment: @AndrewSchulman: Solaris.

Comment: I don't have access to a suitable Solaris system any more but it should be fairly easy to gather the information you want from the prtdiag output using the standard shell tools.

Answer (score 1):

just use psrinfo.

```
$ psrinfo 
0       on-line   since 07/21/2013 05:13:26
1       on-line   since 07/21/2013 05:13:24
```

however if you really want to check processor state then use either kstat or
a correct system call thus :

```
System Calls                                    processor_info(2)

NAME
     processor_info - determine type and status of a processor

SYNOPSIS
     #include <sys/types.h>
     #include <sys/processor.h>

     int        processor_info(processorid_t         processorid,
     processor_info_t *infop);

DESCRIPTION
     The processor_info() function returns the status of the pro-
     cessor  specified  by  processorid  in  the processor_info_t
     structure pointed to by infop.

     The  structure  processor_info_t  contains   the   following
     members:

     int      pi_state;
     char     pi_processor_type[PI_TYPELEN];
     char     pi_fputypes[PI_FPUTYPE];
     int      pi_clock;

     The pi_state member is the current state of  the  processor,
     either P_ONLINE, P_OFFLINE, P_NOINTR, P_FAULTED, P_SPARE, or
     P_POWEROFF.

     The pi_processor_type  member  is  a  null-terminated  ASCII
     string specifying the type of the processor.

     The pi_fputypes member is  a  null-terminated  ASCII  string
     containing the comma-separated types of floating-point units
     (FPUs) attached to the processor. This string will be  empty
     if no FPU is attached.

     The pi_clock member is the processor clock frequency rounded
     to the nearest megahertz. It may be  0 if not known.

RETURN VALUES
     Upon successful completion, 0 is returned. Otherwise,  -1 is
     returned and  errno is set to indicate the error.
```